# Trie/Decision Tree for Conditions/Queries

Tags: conditional-statements, decision-tree, rules, trie

I have set of queries and I get an Object at a time and I want to figure out the object satisfies which of the queries.

For example the queries look like

1) Customers with Age > 25 and NetWorth >= 100000
2) Customers with Address Contains "USA"
3) Customers with Age > 30 and Address contains "USA"

Below is the structure of Customer class

```
class Customer {
     public String Name;
     public int Age;
     public int NetWorth;
     public string Address;                 
}
```

Is there a way to build a trie like structure where I do not need to match the Customer with each query one by one as I can have a very large number of queries. I want to support >, >=, <, <=, = , !=, contains, !contains, empty, !empty operators.

I search on internet but could not find a specific algorithm I can use.
Before I build something I want to know if there is a known solution already exists.

I want to do this in C#.

**Update**
I thought more about it and seems like I can also build a decision tree, but not sure given a large set of queries how can I build a decision tree of minimal length.

Thanks,